# How to set id of spring repository entry to exact value?

Tags: java, spring

I have a entity class like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Employee{
     @Id
     private Long id;
     private String name;
}
```

and repository:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long>{}
```

Now, in my service class I have:

```
EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

public void addEmployee(EmployeeForm employeeForm){
//EmployeeForm is simple inteface
    Employee employee = new Employee(employeeForm.getId(), employeeForm.getName());
    employeeRepository.save(employee);
}
```

This will assign some id to the employee, ignoring id I got from `EmployeeForm`.

Because I need to import list of employees from some other place, and there is already id assigned to each employee, how can I make `EmployeeRepository` to register each employee with id I gave it?

Comment: If you're going to set the Id yourself, you've already done enough, just the @Id annotation is ok.

Comment: I was missing `@NoArgsConstructor`, and in Postman I was supposed to fully match "id" as it was in `EmployeeForm`. 
`employeeRepository.save(employee)` works fine with user set ID, it doesn't override it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are missing: @Entity on your Employee Entity, the other should be done by it self. 
You can check extra for a difference between long and Long, but this should not cause a problem as it is.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Actually, I've already added @Entity, but when you mentioned Long, I remembered that I should be using it instead of long when I'm dealing with repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing `@NoArgsConstructor`, and in Postman I was supposed to fully match "id" as it was in `EmployeeForm`. `employeeRepository.save(employee)` works fine with user set ID, it doesn't override it.